# How to read RSS for Bot Builder

Tags: rss, botframework, azure-bot-service

May I ask about how to read RSS in Nodejs for Bot Builder?

Here with my sample RSS from URL.

```
<rss>
   <channel> 
      <item>
         <title>A- Title</title>
         <description>A - Description</description>
    </item>
      <item>
         <title>B-Title</title>
         <description>B - Description</description>
    </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

I tried the XMLHttprequest but can't.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as there is [SyndicationFeed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) to read RSS feed in C#, there are various ways in which you can read RSS feeds in NodeJS for bot builder:

- Make use of [rss-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rss-parser) which helps to parse RSS from a URL or an XML string.
- Try [node-feedparser](https://github.com/danmactough/node-feedparser) which parses RSS, Atom and RDF feeds in NodeJS.
- You can also refer to [node-parse-rss](https://github.com/dwyl/node-parse-rss).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm using the SyndicationFeed for C#.